# Identity equality for methods in a loop

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
def a():
    pass

def comp():
    for f in (a,):
        if f is a:
            print("Identity")
        elif f == a:
            print("Equality")

comp()
```

I create a function `a`, and a function `comp` which checks, for all functions in the tuple `(a,)`, if they're either identical to `a` (`f is a`), or equal to it (`f == a`). Unsurprisingly, this code prints the word "Identity".

However, this is no longer the case if I turn those functions into instance methods of a class `Test`:

```
class Test(object):
    def a(self):
        pass

    def comp(self):
        for f in (self.a,):
            if f is self.a:
                print("Identity")
            elif f == self.a:
                print("Equality")

t = Test()
t.comp()
```

To my great surprise, this prints "Equality" instead of "Identity". Indeed, if we put `print(id(f), id(self.a))` inside the `for` loop, it will print different identity values. As I'd expect, both identities are different from `id(Test.a)`.

Why is this? Why do the methods seemingly get copied by the for loop, when the plain functions do not?

Comment: What did you expect their relationship to be? Method objects are created each time you look them up on an instance (they are the result of *binding* the function to an instance).